# Changing fahrenheit to kelvin in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to change fahrenheit to Kelvin anf the formula is `K = 5/9 (° F - 32) + 273`

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double const changeToC = 32.0;
double const changeToK = 273.16;

void temperatures(double n);

int main(void)
{
    int q = 'q';
    double userNumber;

    printf("please enter fahrenheit number: \n");
    scanf("%f", &userNumber);

    while (userNumber != q)
    {
        temperatures(userNumber);
        printf("\n");
        printf("please enter fahrenheit number: \n");
        scanf("%f", &userNumber);
    }
}

void temperatures(double n)
{
    double celsius, kelvin;

    celsius = 5.0 / 9.0 * (n - changeToC);
    kelvin = 5.0 / 9.0 (n - changeToC) + changeToK;

    printf("fahrenheit is: %.2f - celsius is: %.2f - kelvin is: %.2f", 
           n, celsius, kelvin);
}
```

I need the input to get a fahrenheit in double, and print the value of celsius and kelvin.

In the fahrenheit to kelvin(`kelvin = 5.0 / 9.0 (n - changeToC) + changeToK;`) line I'm getting an error:

> called object type double is not function or function pointer

Can you please tell me what this means?

Comment: To read `double`, you _have_ to use `%lf` as conversion in `scanf(3)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed the multiplication operator, `*`

```
kelvin = 5.0 / 9.0 * (n - changeToC) + changeToK;
```

Without the multiplication operator, the compiler treats the parentheses `()` as the function call operator.

Comment: Another problem with the code: scanf("%f", &userNumber); should be scanf("%lf", &userNumber); because %f expect a float instead of double.

Comment: @fbafelipe: `%f` expects a **double**.

Comment: @user1959174: that advice is wrong, the type you need in that scanf is `double`, not float. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html

Comment: @user1959174: read that link I pointed to. `%le` is `%e` (conversion specifer) with an `l` length modifier. The effect of `l` on `e` conversion is described in that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
kelvin = 5.0 / 9.0 * (n - changeToC) + changeToK;
```

Place the multiplication operator.. this solves your issue